# What is the replacement for IncludeInAll(...)?

Tags: .net, elasticsearch, nest

Using Elasticsearch.NET/NEST v5.5, I need to index `Id` (GUID) fields for searching directly, but do not want them analyzed or included in global (`_all`) searches.

We are upgrading from a much older version, and we used `StringPropertyDescriptor.Index(Index.NotAnalyzed)` before. We can no longer do that, and must do `.Index(true)` instead, so the field will be available for searching.

But we do not want the field to be used during global/_all searches, and thus, we were going to use `.IncludeInAll(false)`, but this is marked as deprecated and [has already been removed from the source](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-net/commit/17eb95bee01f9fd63759fd2a0a0df54d765ec43e).

So, how can we map a field so it **is indexed** but is **not in the _all field/global search**?

**Current Attempt**

`properties.Keyword(p => p
    .Name(o => o.SomeId)
    .IncludeInAll(false) // Deprecated!
    .Index(true));`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`IncludeInAll()` been removed in the `master` branch because [the `_all` field is to be removed in Elasticsearch 6.0](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/19784). The recommendation is that if you're currently using the `_all` field and would like to achieve similar functionality in 6.0+, you should use [`copy_to` fields](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/copy-to.html) to copy any fields that you'd like to search on into your own dedicated *all*-like field.

It's marked as `Obsolete` in the `5.x` branch from which NEST 5.x are built so that client consumers are aware of this upcoming change.

Your current attempt is correct; you could remove `.Index(true)` if you want as that is the default behaviour.